# Java access array from inside another class method

Tags: java, arrays, class, tostring

I need to access an array that is in a different class without using a getter. I have a scanner passed to a method which creates the array then calls a method to recursively fill the array with the data from a file. I then need to access the toString method and use the array from that class (Student[] list).

```
Public class Test
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
 int actual = 0;
File input = new File("input.txt");
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("output.txt"));
Scanner scan = new Scanner(input);
C155.createList(scan);
actual = C155.getSize();
// writer.write(C155.toString(C155.list, ??????));
writer.close();
}
  }

public class C155 {
public static final int MAXSIZE = 22;
  private static int size = 0;
  public static Student[] createList(Scanner scan)
  {
    Student[] list = new Student[MAXSIZE];
    return populateList(list, scan);
  }
  private static Student[] populateList( Student[] list, Scanner scan )   
  {
    Student s;
    if ( size < MAXSIZE && scan.hasNext() )
     {
      s = new Student(scan.next(), scan.next(),scan.next(),
                      scan.nextDouble(), scan.nextInt());
       list[size] = s;
       size++;
       System.out.println(s);
       return populateList(list, scan);
     }
     else
    return list;
}
public static String toString(Student[] list, int n)
{
    String all= "All Students \n";
    for (int x = 0; x <= n; x++)
    {
        all += list[x].toString() + "\n";
    }
    return all;
}
```

I need to call the toString method (which requires the Student[] list)from the Test class but do not really know the best way to besides creating a get method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a note, all the methods in class C155 are static, which is probably not the best approach.

To answer your question though, your method createList(Scanner scan) has a return type of Student[]. That's where you would obtain a reference to that array in your main method.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(input);
Student[] studentArray = C155.createList(scan); <------
actual = C155.getSize();
writer.write(C155.toString(studentArray, studentArray.length())); <------
writer.close();
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I never even considered storing the array while calling the method!

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to access the list if you return it by method? Just do this:

```
Student[] list = C155.createList(scan);
writer.write(C155.toString(list, list.length()));
```